# Checking membership of object in set without pattern matching

Tags: scala

I'm curious in how to best structure code that checks for membership of an instance of an ADT in a set of elements without using pattern matching.

Given the following ADT, methods and functions, which would be seen as the idiomatic way to check for membership in Scala?

```
sealed trait Code {
  def isEven: Boolean
  def isOdd: Boolean
  def isOther: Boolean
}
case class Even(num: Int) extends Code {
  def isEven = true
  def isOdd = false
  def isOther = false
}
case class Odd(num: Int) extends Code {
  def isEven = false
  def isOdd = true
  def isOther = false
}

case class Other(num: Double) extends Code {
  def isEven: Boolean = false
  def isOdd: Boolean = false
  def isOther = true
}


object Code {
  val EvensBelow5: Seq[Code] = Seq(
    Even(0),
    Even(2),
    Even(4)
  )
  val EvensAbove5: Seq[Code] = Seq(
    Even(6),
    Even(8)
  )

  val OddCodes: Seq[Code] = Seq(
    Odd(1),
    Odd(3),
    Odd(5)
  )

  val OtherCode: Code = Other(1.1)


  def isEvenBelow5(code: Code) = EvensBelow5.contains(code)
  def isEvenAbove5(code: Code) = EvensAbove5.contains(code)
  def isOdd(code: Code) = OddCodes.contains(code)
  def isOther(code: Code) = OtherCode == code
  def isOf(code: Code, codes: Seq[Code]) =
    codes.contains(code)
}
```

**Setup**

```
import Code._

val even: Code = Even(2)
val odd: Code = Odd(1)
val other: Code = Other(1.1)
```

**1) Would it be using methods?**

```
even.isOdd
odd.isEven
other.isOther
```

**2) Would it be using membership check or equality**

```
EvensBelow5.contains(even)
EvensAbove5.contains(even)
OddCodes.contains(odd)
other == OtherCode
```

**3) Would it be using functions that rely on values on the companion object?**

```
isEvenBelow5(even)
isOdd(odd)
isOther(other)
```

**4) Would it be using functions that receive all values?**

```
isOf(even, EvensBelow5)
isOf(even, EvensAbove5)
isOf(odd, OddCodes)
isOf(other, Seq(OtherCode))
```

**5) Would it be another way?**

Maybe something that I have not listed which is not pattern matching.

**Bonus question:**

Would the functions that rely on values / state on the companion object (`isEvenBelow5`, `isEvenAbove5`, `isOdd`, `isOther`) be considered purely functional?

Comment: The "best" way to do anything is always a matter of context. Since we have no way of knowing what you're trying to do, we have no way of knowing what the relative merits of the different approaches are.

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, and find out which of the suggestions is indeed the better one, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226). You have included usage examples, which is a good start, but we need the context the code naturally presides in as well.

Comment: Currently it looks like hypothetical code, and we don't deal with that. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].